# UicollectionViewCell on cell select change Border colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a custom `UICollectionVIewCell`. When the user selects a cell I want the border of the cell to be Red in color and when the user de-selects it I want to clear-color the border of the cell.

How is this possible?

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomeCollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomeCollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

}
```

Comment: It would be simpler to override `CustomeCollectionViewCell` `setSelected:animated:`...

Comment: You shouldn't give the red color in numberOfItemsInSection method. You should do it in - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; method

Comment: @Larme My mistake. I pasted the wrong code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *img =[[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"imageName"];
    cell.backgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:img]];

    cell.layer.borderWidth=10;
    cell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor greenColor].CGColor;

    return cell;
}
```

This is working code in my app. Make sure that there is borderwidth if you giving bordercolor.

Comment: How do i remove border colour when i de-select the cell ?

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Answer (score 1):

Use built in methods of `UICollectionViewCell` class.
You need override `setHighlighted:` method.

```
- (void)setHightlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
  [super ....];
  self.something = highlighted ? red : blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
cell.layer.borderColor
```

to change color border

Comment: Just a note, this take a `CGColor`, not a `UIColor`.  So when setting the border color use `UIColor.blackColor().CGColor` (Swift).